# Is there a way to add lazy evaluation for methods during compilation or sources processing?

Tags: java

I don't like this code, but I like what it does (retrieves something lazily):

```
private final HugeMatrix storedMatrix;

public HugeMatrix matrix() {
    if (this.storedMatrix == null) {
        this.storedMatrix = // compute the huge matrix
    }
    return storedMatrix;
}
```

I like this code, and I want it to do the same thing the above code does:

```
@Lazy
public HugeMatrix matrix() {
    return // compute the huge matrix
}
```

The private field and check are boilerplate. Can they be auto-generated for each annotated method with some tool similar to Project Lombok? Does such tool exist? Doesn't matter whether it operates on bytecode or on generated sources, the only thing that matters is that the original source code should be nice to read.

I would write a tool myself, but I don't know what to use (I already tried AspectJ and annotation processors for that purpose; these things seem to be unsuited for the task, but again I might be wrong about them).

Comment: Speaking of Lombok, you have @Getter annotation with `lazy` parameter. https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterLazy.html But, frankly speaking, I don't like their idea to translate it to double-check locking getter.

Comment: @mkrakhin I've seen that and I wonder why it isn't implemented the way I described it. Is there a reason to have the field in your code, when all you need is the method's behavior?

Comment: well, you have to store cache somewhere.

Comment: You might have a look at JCache (JSR107) that way needs no private field and has better memory handling as it throws the hudge matrix away and recalcs later under some (configurable) circumstances.

Comment: @mkrakhin That is the point. It should be stored in a private field, and littering your code with that field and initialization checks is not cool. That's why I want the field and the check to be generated.

Comment: @SirRotN And I still have to write the code that puts the matrix into the cache. I don't want to write any code for that. Moreover, I don't need a whole new facility that throws the matrix away, that's the garbage collector's job. The matrix will be disposed when the objects holding it are disposed, simple as that.

Comment: It's understandable that you want to write less code. But using a magic tool that looks simple on the first sight may create more problems down the road. Stupid but straightforward code is more maintainable in the long run.

Comment: @bayou.io The problem is not that I want to write less code. Writing code is easy. I want to *read* less code.

Comment: yes, it's the reading part that will get more difficult in magic code than in plain code. it seems obvious, right? Lazy is Lazy. but if someone wants to know the exact semantics, it'll be a little more work to discover. that is just my general experience.

Comment: @bayou.io That is flawed logic. Would you prefer `if (Debug.enabled == true) {checkCondition(a,b);}` to assertions? There was time when they weren't present in the language. The same can be said about many other features. Magic doesn't mean difficult reading.

Comment: It depends the specific use case. And yes, if a syntax/tool is standard, or widely-used, we have no excuse not understanding its magic. but let me ask you this, suppose the language does not provide an official `assert`, would you use some macro / pre-processor to simulate that? or would you just write that boiler plate code? Personally I'd rather do the stupider but simpler thing.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/)'s [Lazy](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/lang/Lazy.html):

```
@Lazy HugeMatrix matrix = // compute the huge matrix
```

If you don't know about [groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/), it's a language where not only is all Java code valid (so you can already write it!) it also has a more concise syntax to use. It compiles down to Java byte code, so no additional runtime requirements. It's also dynamic if you want, and it's supported out of the box by [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/groovy.html).

In general, if you hate boilerplate, you'll love groovy!

This, for example, is an [immutable](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/Immutable.html) class that has an [equality contract](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/transform/EqualsAndHashCode.html) implemented:

```
@Immutable
class Person {
    String first, last
    int age
}
```

That's it!

Note `@Immutable` gives you `@EqualsAndHashCode` but you can use `@EqualsAndHashCode` instead if you don't want immutable.

Usage:

```
def c1 = new Customer(first:'Tom', last:'Jones', age:21);
def c2 = new Customer("Tom", 'Jones', 21);
assertEquals(c1, c2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily write it in one line :)

```
if(this.storedMatrix==null){this.storedMatrix=compute()}return storedMatrix;
```

Joking aside, JSR-107 can be close to what you need. Also, if you can use Java 8, lambda expressions may help reduce boilerplate code like this.